# NPM: Refuses to install modules; Code 2, Make 129

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to self host my web application I made, but cannot install any modules.
It exits with code 2 and shows a Make error 129.

I ran npm i with a few modules and this was the result:

```
C:\Users\reece\Desktop\ARCS\friendly-guacamole>npm i markdown-it express socket.io striptags cors eiows @socket.io/admin-ui
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\reece\\Desktop\\ARCS\\friendly-guacamole\\node_modules\\@types',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\reece\Desktop\ARCS\friendly-guacamole\node_modules\@types\node'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\reece\\Desktop\\ARCS\\friendly-guacamole\\node_modules\\@types\\node'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\reece\\Desktop\\ARCS\\friendly-guacamole\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\reece\Desktop\ARCS\friendly-guacamole\node_modules\@types\node'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\reece\\Desktop\\ARCS\\friendly-guacamole\\node_modules\\@types\\node'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path C:\Users\reece\Desktop\ARCS\friendly-guacamole\node_modules\eiows
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c make
npm ERR! git clone -c advice.detachedHead=false --depth 1 https://github.com/nodejs/node -b `(node --version)` nodejs/src/node
npm ERR! error: unknown option `version)`'
npm ERR! usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     -v, --verbose         be more verbose
npm ERR!     -q, --quiet           be more quiet
npm ERR!     --progress            force progress reporting
npm ERR!     --reject-shallow      don't clone shallow repository
npm ERR!     -n, --no-checkout     don't create a checkout
npm ERR!     --bare                create a bare repository
npm ERR!     --mirror              create a mirror repository (implies bare)
npm ERR!     -l, --local           to clone from a local repository
npm ERR!     --no-hardlinks        don't use local hardlinks, always copy
npm ERR!     -s, --shared          setup as shared repository
npm ERR!     --recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]
npm ERR!                           initialize submodules in the clone
npm ERR!     --recursive[=<pathspec>]
npm ERR!                           alias of --recurse-submodules
npm ERR!     -j, --jobs <n>        number of submodules cloned in parallel
npm ERR!     --template <template-directory>
npm ERR!                           directory from which templates will be used
npm ERR!     --reference <repo>    reference repository
npm ERR!     --reference-if-able <repo>
npm ERR!                           reference repository
npm ERR!     --dissociate          use --reference only while cloning
npm ERR!     -o, --origin <name>   use <name> instead of 'origin' to track upstream
npm ERR!     -b, --branch <branch>
npm ERR!                           checkout <branch> instead of the remote's HEAD
npm ERR!     -u, --upload-pack <path>
npm ERR!                           path to git-upload-pack on the remote
npm ERR!     --depth <depth>       create a shallow clone of that depth
npm ERR!     --shallow-since <time>
npm ERR!                           create a shallow clone since a specific time
npm ERR!     --shallow-exclude <revision>
npm ERR!                           deepen history of shallow clone, excluding rev
npm ERR!     --single-branch       clone only one branch, HEAD or --branch
npm ERR!     --no-tags             don't clone any tags, and make later fetches not to follow them
npm ERR!     --shallow-submodules  any cloned submodules will be shallow
npm ERR!     --separate-git-dir <gitdir>
npm ERR!                           separate git dir from working tree
npm ERR!     -c, --config <key=value>
npm ERR!                           set config inside the new repository
npm ERR!     --server-option <server-specific>
npm ERR!                           option to transmit
npm ERR!     -4, --ipv4            use IPv4 addresses only
npm ERR!     -6, --ipv6            use IPv6 addresses only
npm ERR!     --filter <args>       object filtering
npm ERR!     --also-filter-submodules
npm ERR!                           apply partial clone filters to submodules
npm ERR!     --remote-submodules   any cloned submodules will use their remote-tracking branch
npm ERR!     --sparse              initialize sparse-checkout file to include only files at root
npm ERR!     --bundle-uri <uri>    a URI for downloading bundles before fetching from origin remote
npm ERR!
npm ERR! make: *** [Makefile:4: default] Error 129
```

I am using npm 9.6.3 with NodeJS v19.9.0, and have reinstalled twice, with the second one using node version manager.